# How to determine the split in a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning

The goal here is to grow a decision tree with depth 1 based on the small dataset below. I can use the sum of squared errors as measure to select the best variable split.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|r|}
\hline \text { Attribute } 1\left(x_1\right) & \text { Attribute } 2\left(x_2\right) & y \\
\hline 1 & 2 & 3.5 \\
\hline 1.3 & 2 & 2.3 \\
\hline 1.3 & 2 & 3.3 \\
\hline 1 & 2 & 2.3 \\
\hline 1.3 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline 1 & 8 & 4.9 \\
\hline 1 & 2 & 1.3 \\
\hline 1.4 & 2 & 6.3 \\
\hline 1 & 2 & 5.3 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

According to the assignment this is the rule to determine the best split. The interpretation  of this rule is clear to me.

$$
E(s)=E\left(R_{\ell}\right)+E\left(R_r\right)=\sum_{\left\{\mathbf{x}_i \in R_{\ell}(j, s)\right\}}\left(y_i-\hat{y}_{\ell}\right)^2+\sum_{\left\{\mathbf{x}_i \in R_r(j, s)\right\}}\left(y_i-\hat{y}_r\right)^2
$$

My question is: **Is it a priori possible to determine the best split?**

The method I have in mind is not even manually feasible, because I would first loop over the attributes and within each attribute I would calculate the range of the attribute and within that range starting with the minimum -> calculate the $E[s]$ -> increase with 0.1 -> calculate new $E[s]$ -> until the max of the range is reached. Then I would do the same for the second attribute. At the end I would check the $S_{best}:\left(x_?, ?.??\right)$ which resulted in the lowest sum of squared error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why increase by 0.1 in your method?